# Tab bar controll delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs

I have 4 tabs . In tab nr 1 i have a list with songs . When i select a one of them i want to go to the tab nr 2 and play the song.

I was trying this :

First tab :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     PlaySoundViewController *playSoundViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"playSoundVC"];
    self.delegate=playSoundViewController;
    [self.delegate viewDidChanged:self newSoundSelected:YES index:indexPath.row array:coll2];


    NSLog(@"%@",self.delegate);
    [ self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];}
```

Delegate it's ok, tab is changing but no song.

if i add this line :

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:playSoundViewController animated:YES];
```

The song is playing , but the tab is not changing .

Any ideea about how can i solve this , please?

This is the method from delegate:

```
-(void) viewDidChanged: (MusicViewController *)controller newSoundSelected:(BOOL) newSoundSelected index:(NSInteger)indexValue array:(NSArray*) array{

    self.newSoundSelected=newSoundSelected;
    self.playlistArray=array;
    self.currentIndex=indexValue;

   [ self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];


    NSLog(@"delegate called");


}
```

Comment: try changing tab number to 1 since you have two tabs only

Comment: in PlaySoundViewController.h file  keep some property to keep track of which song to play and on didSelect when you instantiate the playSoundViewController update that property, in viewDidLoad call the method to play that song.